# Word meaning "convert a variable value to a constant value"

Tags: single-word-requests

Perhaps this belongs on stackoverflow, but since it could have some applicability to non-tech contexts, thought I'd post here.

Is there a word that means "make something that is variable constant"?

For example, in programming, I might have a variable `queueSize` that could be set to different values for different queues. Later I decide to make this a fixed (constant) value for all queues. What is a word to describe this conversion?

*Edit*

A real-world (non-programming) example is converting from a variable tax-rate to a flat (constant) tax-rate. I proposed below that, in light of this example, the word `flatten` could be used to answer my question. However, this word does not conventionally mean "to make constant", and has other meanings in the context of several programming languages.

*Edit*

To be clear, I'm not looking for a word/expression the means changing a variable from one type to another (casting). Rather, I mean keeping the type the same, but changing a field from a variable to a constant value.

Comment: This is getting very much into coding, and may end up being inappropriate for this venue. But: When you say "*changing*" a field, do you mean just *assigning* it a *value* that is then not expected to change? E.g., you're not doing anything to the variable at all, just to its value?

Comment: In terms of coding, I think I mean converting a variable to a constant. In C, I might change a variable which can be set during runtime to a define which never (and cannot) change during the lifetime of the application.

Comment: Ah, so in a previous version of the code it was a variable. Then in a future version of the code you made it a `#define` (or equivalent)? I think that's very much a question you should ask developers about :)

Comment: I'd say something like "fix" or <tip-of-my-tongue...>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say "make a constant of" (or some similar form with "make constant"); for example, "I made `queueSize` into a constant".  More generally, consider *[fixate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fixate)*, "To make something fixed and stable; to fix".  In a programming context, *fixate* may be perfectly acceptable even where *fix* (with usual meaning of "convert real to integer") is not.

Without more context, I hesitate to recommend `cast` because I don't know of a language with a `cast` keyword that allows casting a variable to static.  I imagine *make static* may mislead some as well, because `static` has multiple meanings like non-dynamically allocated; in file scope; or single instance in class.

Comment: Yeah, "make constant" suffers the same problems as "make static" and "make fixed" since `const(ant)`, `static`, and `fixed` are very common keywords across languages with `overloaded` meanings.

Comment: I think "make constant" is less confusing that "make static" when it comes to converting a variable into an "invariable". static variables are still mutable/ writable whereas const variables are (ideally) immutable.

Answer (score 6):

For clarity and concision, I'd recommend using "**make static**" or "**make constant**".

It's short, only 10-11 characters depending on how you treat the space; unambiguous; and unobscure. Sometimes a single word isn't what you want so much as something short and to the point.

Answer (score 3):

"Pin down", "fix", or "stabilize" can all mean to take something moving, unstable, or unknown and make it known and stationary, if you want non-programming answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes [`cast`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) is the term we would use in the industry to imply conversion from one type to another..

> I casted the int to a long.

Or, you could say *make immutable* if you mean to say *remove the write flag*. In a lot of languages this is simply done with a flag anyway and so under the hood nothing drastic is happening.. Some crappy languages call this [*freezing*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx)

Note some languages differentiate between *casting* and *converting* on the basis of whether or not it merely reinterprets the underlying data, or converts it to a different representation.

If you're going from a complex data structure, to a simple the one the terms used are *marshal* or [*serialize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: Never heard anyone say "casted." It's always `cast`, past & present.  I've also never heard the word "cast" used to describe making something `static`.

Comment: There is simply no such word as ***∗casted***.  The OED has the verb **cast** as invariant in its past and past participle alike.  It works like **set**: it doesn’t change.

Comment: [Wiktionary disagrees.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/casted) Stop trolling.

Comment: Though wiktionary is questionable, it does say that it is 'nonstandard'.

Comment: [I'm just telling you what they say.](https://www.google.com/search?q=casted+variable)

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate all the answers so far.

One word which does not conventionally mean "to make constant", but that I think could be (read: I'd like to see) co-opted for that purpose, is *[flatten](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flatten)*. For example, if the US were to switch from a variable tax rate to a flat one, people might say "in 2012 the President flattened the tax rate".

Comment: `flatten` is generally reserved concept (and/or word) in [java](https://fynanz.hipchat.com/history/room/62367/2012/08/06/?h=wkhtmltopdf), [ruby](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+flatten+collection&aq=1&oq=java+flatten&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=ruby+flatten+&oq=ruby+flatten+&gs_l=serp.3..0i7l3j0.36646.37061.1.37210.4.4.0.0.0.0.83.289.4.4.0...0.0...1c.TbjdyZSFqXI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=7bf8912c271e26df&biw=1066&bih=945), and [.NET](http://www.dotnetperls.com/flatten-array)

Comment: Well, it's your program, you can use the word however you like. But I'd think this usage would be confusing. Flatten in the tax context means to flatten *the curve*.